# replace column value with subsequent one from list of uniques

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of ~1000 unique items

```
np.random.seed(0)
unique1 = sorted(list(np.random.choice(np.arange(2000), 1000, False)))
```

and a `pandas` `df.column` of ~12 mil lines with just integers from this list.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.sort(np.random.choice(unique1[1:], 12000000))})
```

What I need to do is create a new column with always the previous element in the list of uniques than the one in my original column.

I have tried doing it with `apply` but the efficiency is laughable, and with a common loop which is kind of ok (~2 mins on my system), but I am wondering if I could get there more efficiently (smaller numbers used for illustration purposes):

```
np.random.seed(0)
unique1 = sorted(list((np.random.choice(np.arange(20), 10, False))))
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.sort(np.random.choice(unique1[1:], 15))})

unique2 = unique1[1:]
df['b'] = df.a.apply(lambda x: unique1[unique2.index(x)])

newCol = []
for item in list(df.a):
    newCol.append(unique1[unique2.index(item)])
df['c'] = newCol
print(df, unique1)
     a   b   c
0    2   1   1
1    2   1   1
2    4   2   2
3    6   4   4
4    8   6   6
5    8   6   6
6    8   6   6
7   10   8   8
8   13  10  10
9   13  10  10
10  17  13  13
11  18  17  17
12  18  17  17
13  19  18  18
14  19  18  18 [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 13, 17, 18, 19]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using [`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations), which does a linear search through all of the unique values.

If you can afford the space to build a dict, you can turn this into a constant-time lookup:

```
unique2 = {value: index for index, value in enumerate(unique1[1:])}
df['b'] = df.a.apply(lambda x: unique1[unique2[x]])
```

If you can't (in which case you should be keeping the values in an array or Slice rather than a list in the first place…), as long as you keep them sorted, you can at least search in logarithmic rather than linear time using [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) or [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
df['b'] = df.a.apply(lambda x: unique1[np.searchsorted(unique2, x)])
```

(This will be faster if `unique2` is an array rather than a list, but only by a constant factor; it's still logarithmic time with a list.)